# how to handle SessionNotFoundException: in selenium

Tags: selenium

I am getting Session Not found exception, not sure why i am missing.
I am calling a method Acti_05CreateNewCUst in the other method TestCase1 and then accessing the same through main function.

When error message is displayed, it is working fine.
BUt when there is no error message, the execution failed and exception is shown

```
  WARN [main] (Log.java:42)- The exception thrown here is :org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session

//A method    
    public class Acti_05CreateNewCust 
    {
        private static WebElement element = null;
        static WebDriverWait wait;

    //Error Message
         public static WebElement errorMsgCust(WebDriver driver)
         {

             try
            {
                wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
                wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(".//*[@id='customerLightBox_footer']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span")));
                Log.warn("Error message element has been identifeid");

            }
             catch(Exception e)
             {
                Log.debug("The exception here for error msg is "+e);
             }
            return driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='customerLightBox_footer']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/span"));
         }
    }


//Calling the method under This method
    public static void  TestCase1() throws Exception 
        {   
            ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData+Constant.File_TestCaseExecSheet, Constant.Sheet2_TestCaseExecSheet);
            driver=ActiAction_03OpenBrowser.openBrowser("Chrome");
            if(Acti_01LoginPage.val_LoginPage(driver)==true)
            {
            ActiAction_01Login.Execute(driver);
            Log.info("Customer has logged in and navigated to Home page");
            takeSnapShot(driver, "TC1");


            Acti_02HmePage.click_linkTasktab(driver).click();
            Log.info("Task Tab has been clicked");
            takeSnapShot(driver, "TC1");

            if(Acti_02HmePage.val_suc_click_linkTasktab(driver)==true)
            {
                Acti_03TaskPage.click_linkProjectCust(driver).click();
                Log.info("Project and Customer link has been clicked");
                takeSnapShot(driver, "TC1");

                if(Acti_03TaskPage.valsuc_click_linkProjectCust(driver)==true)
                {
                    Acti_04ProjandCust.click_BtnCreateCust(driver).click();
                    Log.info("Create Customer Button has been clicked");
                    takeSnapShot(driver, "TC1");

                    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData+Constant.File_TestCaseExecSheet, Constant.Sheet3_TestCaseExecSheet);
                    Log.info("The excelsheet is opened::"+(Constant.Path_TestData+Constant.File_TestCaseExecSheet)+Constant.Sheet3_TestCaseExecSheet);

                    int rownum=ExcelUtils.getrownum(Constant.Sheet3_TestCaseExecSheet);
                    Log.info("The total number of row in::"+Constant.Sheet3_TestCaseExecSheet+" is "+rownum);

                    for(int i=1;i<rownum+1;i++)
                    {
                        Acti_05CreateNewCust.input_TxtCustname(driver).sendKeys(ExcelUtils.getCellData(i,0));
                        Log.info("Customer name has been entered from excelsheet");
                        Acti_05CreateNewCust.input_TxtCustDesc(driver).sendKeys(ExcelUtils.getCellData(i,1));
                        Log.info("Customer Desc has been entered from excelsheet");
                        if(Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_chceckbox1(driver).isSelected())
                        {
                            Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_chceckbox1(driver).click();
                            Log.info("Checkbox 1 has been unselecetd");
                        }
                        if(Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_chceckbox2(driver).isSelected())
                        {
                            Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_chceckbox2(driver).click();
                            Log.info("Checkbox 2 has been unselecetd");
                        }
                        if(Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_chceckbox3(driver).isSelected())
                        {
                            Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_chceckbox3(driver).click(); 
                            Log.info("Checkbox 3 has been unselecetd");
                        }

                        Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_BtnCreateCust1(driver).click();
                        Log.info("Create Button has been clicked on New Customer Creation Page");
                        takeSnapShot(driver, "TC1");

                        try
                        {
                            if(Acti_05CreateNewCust.errorMsgCust(driver).isDisplayed())
                            {
                                Log.warn("The error msg exist ");
                                takeSnapShot(driver, "WarnOmCustomerCreation Page");
                                Acti_05CreateNewCust.click_BtnCancel(driver).click();
                                Acti_05CreateNewCust.close_popup(driver);
                                Log.warn("Customer has not been created successfully");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                if(Acti_04ProjandCust.val_newcustomer(driver, ExcelUtils.getCellData(i,0))==true)
                                {
                                Log.info("Customer has been created successfully");
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    Log.fatal("Customer has not been created successfully");
                                }
                            }
                        }catch(Exception e)
                        {
                            Log.debug("The exception is thrown here"+e);
                        }
                        driver.close();

                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    Log.fatal("There is someissue with Project&Customer tab, please check it");
                    driver.close();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Log.fatal("There is someissue with task tab, please check it");
                driver.close();
            }


            ActiAction_02LogOut.Execute(driver);
            }
            else
            {
                Log.fatal("The Login Page is not displayed");
                takeSnapShot(driver, "FailLogin");
                driver.close();
            }
        }


//Callin the same through main
    public class MainDriveScenario 
    {


        public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
        {

            //ExcelUtils obj1=new ExcelUtils();
            ScenarioDetails.setuplog();

            ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData+Constant.File_TestCaseExecSheet,Constant.Sheet1_TestCaseExecSheet);

            int rownum1=ExcelUtils.getrownum(Constant.Sheet1_TestCaseExecSheet);

            for(int i=1;i<rownum1+1;i++)
            {

                String Action_Execute=ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 2);
                if(Action_Execute.equalsIgnoreCase("YES"))
                {
                    String Action_testcaseId=ExcelUtils.getCellData(i, 0);

                    switch(Action_testcaseId)
                    {
                    case "TC1":
                        ScenarioDetails.TestCase1();
                        break;

                    case "TC2":
                        ScenarioDetails.TestCase2();
                        break;
                    case "TC3":
                        ScenarioDetails.TestCase3();
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Default value");
                        break;
                    }
                    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData+Constant.File_TestCaseExecSheet,Constant.Sheet1_TestCaseExecSheet);
                    ExcelUtils.setCellData("Executed",Constant.Path_TestData+Constant.File_TestCaseExecSheet, i, 4);
                }
                else
                {
                    ExcelUtils.setExcelFile(Constant.Path_TestData+Constant.File_TestCaseExecSheet,Constant.Sheet1_TestCaseExecSheet);
                    ExcelUtils.setCellData("NotExecuted",Constant.Path_TestData+Constant.File_TestCaseExecSheet, i, 4);
                }

            }

        }
    }

The message displayed in console:

    WARN [main] (Log.java:42)- The exception thrown here is :org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException: no such session
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.19.346078 (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 188 milliseconds
    Build info: version: '2.48.2', revision: '41bccdd', time: '2015-10-09 19:55:52'
    System info: host: 'A4ML10736', ip: '172.23.38.47', os.name: 'Windows 8', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.2', java.version: '1.7.0_45'
    *** Element info: {Using=id, value=logoutLink}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes this issue is due to an outdated driver, but I have found it can also occur if the pom file in maven doesn't list Selenium first, before other dependencies (like AShot, which uses it).